# search in a specific library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: search-results, library, path

i'm trying to make a search in a certain library and try in the searchbox :

```
path:'http://monsite/malib*'
```

but still doesn't have any result

When i look inside the managed path for the items it's always empty while in 2013 it's correctly populated.
And then in wich managed are the uniqueid like in 2013?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct, it should return the results.

**Possible problems:**

1. Make sure that there's no space character before or after the ":" in your query
2. The path you specified isn't correct, just go to your library and copy the path from url and try with it
3. The documents in your library aren't crawled (maybe they were created after the search crawl) so they're not in search results, try running the incremental crawl
4. See what search scope you're using, maybe this library isn't included in that scope

Comment: your third proposition was the correct one.
thanks a lot